# Get annotation generic method argument

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to find the type of method argument using Java reflection.

```
public class ReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = ReflectionTest.class.getDeclaredMethods()[0];
        Parameter parameter = Arrays.stream(method.getParameters())
                .filter(p -> p.isAnnotationPresent(Emits.class))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType)parameter.getParameterizedType();
        Class<?> actualTypeArgument = (Class<?>)parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(actualTypeArgument);//outputs class Person1
        /**
         * I am passing the above Class type to JSON schema generation. Which accepts only Class type.
         */
    }

    void getName(@Emits List<Person1> playlistItems) {}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
    @interface Emits { }
}
```

The above code works perfectly. But when I change the `getName` method signature to

```
void getName(@Emits List<Person1<?>> playlistItems) {}
```

This line would fail

```
Class<?> actualTypeArgument = (Class<?>)parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

with exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl and java.lang.Class are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at reflection.ReflectionTest.main(ReflectionTest.java:25)
```

Is there any way I can fix this issue? I wasted so many hours with no solution for this issue.

Comment: Well, a `ParameterizedTypeImpl` isn't a `Class`, which is why the cast is failing. At the moment all you do with the result is print it, so you don't need the cast at all. I would suggest sticking to the members of `ParameterizedType` rather than assuming any particular concrete implementation.

Comment: Just to add to @JonSkeet's comment, instead of the line you used, use this: `Type actualTypeArgument = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];` The reason is that your class `Person1` is a parametrized type. If instead, `getName()` accepted `List<String>`, you wouldn't face this issue because `String` isn't parametrized.

Comment: @JonSkeet `At the moment all you do with the result is print it`, I am using the `Class` for further processing. This is just an example I have shown here.

Comment: @SuganthanMadhavanPillai: Right. But we don't know what that "further processing" consists of, or how you could use `ParameterizedType` for it instead. So basically the example isn't terribly useful, because you can print the value without the cast which is causing the problem.

Comment: `ParameterizedType parameterType = (ParameterizedType) parameter.getParameterizedType();`
       `ParameterizedType parameterizedTypeImpl = (ParameterizedType) parameterType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];`
        `Class<?> containerParam = (Class<?>) parameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType();`

@JonSkeet I finally end up with this. I am passing this class to generate JSON Schema. Which accepts only `Class` type.

Comment: "I am passing this class to generate JSON Schema. Which accepts only Class type." That information should be in the question then. It's not clear whether using the raw type is really what you need or not, because we still don't really have enough information. But if it works for you, I suggest you update the question to be more useful to others, and then add the solution as an answer.